# How do I build my own material-components-web.min.css?

Tags: material-design, material-components

I've been using material-components-web.min.css to style a Flask app in an MDC web manner. I could go through and edit the colors that I want by hand, but is there a simple method and framework that would allow me to define my own color palette, and then build a material-components-web.min.css with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDC makes it easy to customize colors. You override the default theme color through Sass variables or CSS custom properties. CSS custom properties enables runtime theming.

**[CSS Custom Properties](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)**

```
:root {
  --mdc-theme-secondary: #018786;
  --mdc-theme-secondary-light: #02cecc;
  --mdc-theme-secondary-dark: #004040;
  --mdc-theme-background: #fff;
}
```

**SASS**

First install the @material/theme package with npm

```
npm install --save @material/theme
```

Then create a sass file like this to modify the palette:

```
$mdc-theme-primary: #9c27b0; 
$mdc-theme-secondary: #ffab40;
$mdc-theme-background: #fff;

@import "@material/theme/mdc-theme";
```

Compile the sass file, the outputted CSS file contains all of the rules that will override the default palette. Make sure to link this CSS file in your HTML.

Documentation: https://material.io/components/web/catalog/theme/

If you have any other problems or questions, leave a comment.

Comment: CSS Custom Properties solution does change the color during runtime but it has some problem that colors of some elements will not change. 
Could you please provide me some guide about the SASS solution? I'm not familiar with nodejs&npm&webpack&etc, by which command can I got the `outputted CSS` ?

Comment: You need to run your SASS file through a SASS compiler, here are some: https://sass-lang.com/install